# onBlur and onFocus in separate jQuery

Tags: jquery, onblur, onfocus

This jQuery isn't working. I know it looks kind of odd. But how can I get it to work?

The CSS modifications in the JavaScript section are not functioning. On .blur if the field has nothing in it, the jQuery should change the color of the text box.

On the `blur` if there is nothing in the field, the text should change and the text color should change. On the `focus` if there is "Search Within" in the field, the text should change and the text color should change.

http://jsfiddle.net/7P5J8/

Do I have to remove the inline JavaScript?

Comment: define not working, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If this worked properly what would it do?

Comment: It works what is your problem ?

Comment: @sgarrett The CSS modifications in JavaScript section are not functioning. On `.blur` if the field has nothing in it, the CSS should change the color.

Comment: This question is not useful once your link breaks. You should post your code here instead of on another site.

Comment: You just accepted an answer with a not working JSFiddle!...

Comment: @user1090389: So you're going to check back on a periodic basis to ensure the integrity of that link for future readers, and replace it when it fails?

Comment: @amnotiam Oh... didn't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this and see if it fixes the problem :

```
$("#additionalsearch").focus(function(){
if (this.value == "Search Within")
{
    this.value = "";
    $(this).css('color','#000000');
 }
});

$("#additionalsearch").blur(function(){

        if (this.value == "")
        {
            this.value = "Search Within";
            $(this).css('color','#a9a9a9');
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GhA2u/

Comment: This answer is not useful once your link breaks. You should post your solution here instead of on another site.

Comment: @amnotiam. so as this guy question... **=)** anyway I answered a full answer below.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to remove the inline code, because it runs before the event handlers.
You should keep the HTML for persenation only, All the logic and JavaScript put inside the `<script>`tag and in a .JS file is even better.

[fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/7P5J8/4/)

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#additionalsearch').focus(function() {
        if (this.value === 'Search Within') {
            $(this).css('color', '#000000').val('');
        }
    });
    $('input#additionalsearch').blur(function() {
        if (this.value === '') {
            $(this).css('color', 'red').val('Search Within');
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="additionalsearch" type="text" value="Search Within" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the code through Firebug and see what the css properties/attributes are. Inline should override javascript attribute settings/css styling attributes, unless you use the Important! attribute.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the inline functions are running first, so when the field is blank and you click out, it is set to something with the inline function.  So not matter what, when the jquery onblur is called, the field always has text in it (because even when it doesn't and the onblur is called the inline function adds text before the jquery runs).

Could you elaborate on what you want to occur? Maybe I can help.

Comment: Basically on the `blur` if there is nothing in the field, the text should change and the text color should change. On the `focus` if there is nothing in the field, the text should change and the text color should change.

Comment: So if they click out without adding text, it should re display the 'Search within' but a different color?